# What is exactly a hook in etoolbox

Tags: package-writing, etoolbox, hooks

I understand well the `\apptocmd` and related tools of `etoolbox` package. However, I still not understand what `\appto<hook>{<code>}` and related do, even reading three time the handbook ?

Should package programmer define hook as a macro without argument (like `\myhook`) ? In this case, what is the difference with command patched by `\apptocmd` and related ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The definition of `\appto` is

```
% etoolbox.sty, line 891:
\newrobustcmd{\appto}[2]{%
  \ifundef{#1}
    {\edef#1{\unexpanded{#2}}}
    {\edef#1{\expandonce#1\unexpanded{#2}}}}
```

The first argument should be a parameterless macro. Why not using `\apptocmd`? Because it is much less efficient and it may even not succeed if the replacement text has “non standard” tokens (for instance, characters with a different category code than usual).

Apart from this, the only other difference between `\appto` and `\apptocmd` is that the latter preserves the status of a `\long` (parameterless) macro, whereas `\appto` will always change it to non-`\long`.

Comment: so `\appto` is recommaned for parameterless macro and `\apptocmd` for other macros?

Comment: @Maïeul Exactly so